# Highmaps - Legend Item Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highmaps

I am working with the following `Highmaps` example on JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/legend/padding-itemmargin/

Stackoverflow requires I submit the JSFiddle code:

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=world-population-density.json&callback=?', function (data) {
    // Initiate the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
        chart : {
            borderWidth : 1
        },
        title : {
            text : 'Legend padding and item margin'
        },
        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true
        },
        legend: {
            title: {
                text: 'Individuals per km²'
            },
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            floating: true,
            layout: 'vertical',
            valueDecimals: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)',
            padding: 12,
            itemMarginTop: 0,
            itemMarginBottom: 0,
            symbolRadius: 0,
            symbolHeight: 14,
            symbolWidth: 24
        },
        colorAxis: {
            dataClasses: [{
                to: 3,
                color: 'rgba(19,64,117,0.05)'
            }, {
                from: 3,
                to: 10,
                color: 'rgba(19,64,117,0.2)'
            }, {
                from: 10,
                to: 30,
                color: 'rgba(19,64,117,0.4)'
            }, {
                from: 30,
                to: 100,
                color: 'rgba(19,64,117,0.5)'
            }, {
                from: 100,
                to: 300,
                color: 'rgba(19,64,117,0.6)'
            }, {
                from: 300,
                to: 1000,
                color: 'rgba(19,64,117,0.8)'
            }, {
                from: 1000,
                color: 'rgba(19,64,117,1)'
            }]
        },

        series : [{
            data : data,
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
            joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
            name: 'Population density',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#BADA55'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '/km²'
            }
        }]
    });
});   
});
```

Issue:

When Legend Items are clicked, countries associated with that range are removed from the map.

However, it removes both the fill and the borders.

How to have the borders remain even when countries have been removed?

Answer (score 0):

How about duplicating `mapData`? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gf6jorjm/

Not the best in terms of performance, but you have now two independent maps. Now simply disable border on the second map, to get rid off unnecessary borders (duplicated).